# Select values from first column which are not present in second column using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table as like this

```
mysql> select * from bst;
+------+------+
| n    | p    |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    1 |
|    4 |    2 |
|    5 |    2 |
|    6 |    3 |
|    7 |    3 |
|    8 |    4 |
|    9 |    4 |
|   10 |    5 |
|   11 |    5 |
|   12 |    6 |
|   13 |    6 |
|   14 |    7 |
|   15 |    7 |
|   16 |   15 |
+------+------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to select values in n which are not in p.

Output should be like this

```
8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

But when i tried like this

```
mysql> select n from bst where n not in(select distinct p from bst );
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Where am i going wrong.Pls give me a solid explanatiomn

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`;

```
select t.n
from bst t
where not exists (select 1 from bst t2 where t2.p = t.n);
```

If you want this as a comma-separated list, then you can aggregate:

```
select group_concat(t.n order by t.n)
from bst t
where not exists (select 1 from bst t2 where t2.p = t.n);
```

The reason that `NOT IN` doesn't work is because of the `NULL` value.  When the subquery returns `NULL` then *no values are returned at all by `NOT IN`.  This is because of the semantics of `NULL` -- technically it is treated as "unknown" not as "missing".  So, a `NULL` value is unknown and *could* match any other value.  The `NOT IN` returns `NULL`, which is treated as false.

For this reason, I advise *never* to use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  Always use `NOT EXISTS` (or `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` if you prefer).

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff ,,,but i couldn't fully grasp your first query ..can you give me a more explanation of that query ..thanks a lot for your support

Comment: can you pls give an explanatio fotr this part  bst t
where not exists (select 1 from bst t2 where t2.p = t.n);

Comment: @MidhunRaj . . . I don't know what needs explaining . . . `t` and `t2` are simply aliases for your table to support the correlated subquery.

Comment: thanks a lot man ..now i got it